# Unknown sequence number while processing queue

Tags: android

I have Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit with jdk 6. I am trying to run a "helloworld" example of an Android program in the emulator that I created and when I run the program from Eclipse, it says:

```
[Emulator] [xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[2013-06-03 17:23:40 - Emulator] [xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[2013-06-03 17:23:40 - Emulator] [xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
[2013-06-03 17:23:40 - Emulator] emulator64-arm: ../../src/xcb_io.c:273: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
[2013-06-03 17:23:42 - FirstAndroidApp] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.firstandroidapp.MainActivity activity launch'!
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try to delete the emulator and create a new one. There seems to be a problem with the emulator you have created.

Comment: That may be anything. All you can try is to delete the whole sdk you have and download it again. something is broke there.

Comment: @ihsankocak, did you ever find a solution for your question? Please post it if you did

Comment: @kipkuch i could not fşnd a solution, i recreated the project and it was fixed.

Comment: @Miro Markaravanes downloading and installing the whole 16GB SDK? Can't we confirm it is the error on the side of Eclipse? Because when I installed Luna in Windows, nothing happened, but this is happening in the Linux Ubantu >14. ihsan kocak: If merely recreating the project fixes the problem, is there need to reinstall massive SDK?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android emulator crashes on Ubuntu 11.10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312952/android-emulator-crashes-on-ubuntu-11-10)

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena The latest SDK is just 370 MB. [You can download it here](https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip)

Comment: @Miro Markaravanes [That is a wrong build, requirement was for Ubantu not Windows] More than that, I know this because I am using this for 4 years. After installing you have to update for every OS level and if you don't download the images it is minimum 7GB that you have to download. Please have a look at my answer, where you don't have to download again and again.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312952/android-emulator-crashes-on-ubuntu-11-10

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena Your answer can be right. [This is the linux version](https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip) It is 370 MB as well. You would normally only need the last SDK and probably two others (2.3 and 4.1) that are 500 MB each. So overall 1.37 GB I guess.

Comment: @Miro Markaravanes Sir as I am already using this, thanks for the link. Please ensure that using only 2.3, 4.1 (for dependencies and support-v7) and L-SDK, you can target all the devices in the market.But the question is: why to download even these again and again, when I know that after backing-up and formatting, and then upgrading to new Ubantu, I do not have to download the SDK again? Just restoring and permitting the ownership and execution rights is all I have to do (except in plugin failure). Thanks for the idea and I shall uninstall the unnecessary images and SDK's & gain some space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/25862648/787399 , This could be due to owenership or permission denial.