# IntelliJ Idea 13: execution failed with exit code 139

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I'm using the IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.1 Community Edition.
I can't compile successfully my app.
These are the libraries I'm using:

Library Projects:

- ActionBarSherlock
- Crouton
- Google Play Services
- Inscription
- NineOldAndroids
- PhotoView
- SherlockNavigationDrawer
- ShowcaseView
- StickyListHeaders
- StyledDialogs
- SystemBarTint

JARs:

- Google Play Services jar
- BugSense
- android-support-v4.jar

As suggested by other Stackoverflow questions, I've already updated all in the SDK Manager and in the project there are no `@+/id`.
This is the output:

```
android-apt-compiler: Command "/Users/Rampo/Android IDE/Android SDK Nuovo/build-tools/19.0.1/aapt package -m --auto-add-overlay --extra-packages com.nineoldandroids:com.sherlock.navigationdrawer:com.inscription:eu.inmite.android.lib.dialogs:de.keyboardsurfer.mobile.app.android.widget.crouton:com.actionbarsherlock:com.emilsjolander.components.stickylistheaders:uk.co.senab.photoview:com.google.android.gms:com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:com.github.espiandev.showcaseview --output-text-symbols /Users/Rampo/Library/Caches/IdeaIC13/compile-server/bo2 full guide_e6e9c484/android/intermediate_artifacts/BO2 Full Guide/r_txt -J /Users/Rampo/Library/Caches/IdeaIC13/compile-server/_temp_/android_apt_output8420340299073398749tmp -M /Users/Rampo/Dropbox/Workspace/Apps/BO2 Full Guide/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/Rampo/Dropbox/Workspace/Apps/BO2 Full Guide/res -S /Users/Rampo/Dropbox/Workspace/Librerie/SherlockNavigationDrawer/SherlockNavigationDrawer/res -S /Users/Rampo/Dropbox/Workspace/Librerie/Inscription/Inscription/res -S /Users/Rampo/Dropbox/Workspace/Librerie/Crouton/Crouton/res -S /Users/Rampo/Dropbox/Workspace/Librerie/StickyListHeaders/StickyListHeaders/res -S /Users/Rampo/Dropbox/Workspace/Librerie/SystemBarTint/SystemBarTint/res -S /Users/Rampo/Dropbox/Workspace/Librerie/PhotoView/PhotoView/res -S /Users/Rampo/Dropbox/Workspace/My GitHub/ShowcaseView/ShowcaseView/res -S /Users/Rampo/Dropbox/Workspace/Librerie/NineOldAndroids/NineOldAndroids/res -S /Users/Rampo/Dropbox/Workspace/Librerie/GooglePlayServices/res -S /Users/Rampo/Dropbox/Workspace/Librerie/StyledDialogs/StyledDialogs/res -S /Users/Rampo/Dropbox/Workspace/Librerie/ActionBarSherlock/ActionBarSherlock/res -I /Users/Rampo/Android IDE/Android SDK Nuovo/platforms/android-19/android.jar" execution failed with exit code 139
```

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865748/android-eclipse-error-executing-aapt-return-code-139) SO question. Seems to be a duplicate

Comment: @boxed__l I've tried all the solutions in the answers. Nothing changed

Comment: I think you are just copy pasting your project files. First create hello world app and then step by step add all the files you counted above.Also check your resources folder for problems