# Error after creating an android project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, sdk

Each time I create a project and add, for example, a TextView, Eclipse gives me the error:

Type Error executing aapt: Return code -1073741816 test3 line 1
Android ADT Problem.

Tried to solve the problem by:
deleting the SDK bundle and then downloading it again;
cleaned C drive (as it also used to give an error that res.bin could not be created or something like that);
Plus says 'R cannot be resolved to a variable' when I open the MainActivity.java file.

Any help will be much appretiated

Comment: R cannot be resolved is a standard problem, which can be removed by cleaning the project. **Project -> Clean**

Comment: Possible cause for [Error executing aapt](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7289837/1134705). And here for you [R cannot be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3259974/1134705)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to move your project(eclipse.exe and re install sdk) folder along with Eclipse and sdk to a new directory and since the old one will always reference back to the paths that might contain errors. Once the new directory is up with no errors u can direct the eclipse to your older workspace.